# org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject showing in android

Tags: android, json, android-volley, jsonexception

Iam Creating an android application to read json values webservice. The service returning following json response.

```
[{"pk_int_kv_category_id":1,"vchr_kv_category_name":"Parent","fk_int_kv_category_id":1,"vchr_delete_status":"s","vchr_last_modified_by":1,"vchr_last_modified_time":1},{"pk_int_kv_category_id":2,"vchr_kv_category_name":"Events","fk_int_kv_category_id":1,"vchr_delete_status":"s","vchr_last_modified_by":123,"vchr_last_modified_time":"2017-08-23 14:46:04"}]
```

And the following section of my program fetch the json values from url

```
public void makeJSONRequest(String categoryurl, String JSON_ARRAY, final String pk_int_kv_category_id_obj, final String vchr_kv_category_name_obj, final String fk_int_kv_category_id_obj, final String vchr_delete_status_obj, final String vchr_last_modified_by_obj, final String vchr_last_modified_time_obj) {
    //listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    //newsItems.clear();
    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    pDialog.setMessage("Downloading Latest News...");
    pDialog.show();
    //JSONObject jsonObject = null;

    JsonObjectRequest jsonReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,
            categoryurl, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Response: " + response.toString());
            //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,response.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            if (response != null) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                parseJsonFeed(response, pk_int_kv_category_id_obj, vchr_kv_category_name_obj, fk_int_kv_category_id_obj, vchr_delete_status_obj, vchr_last_modified_by_obj, vchr_last_modified_time_obj);
                hidePDialog();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),error.getMessage().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

    //Creating a request queue
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    //Adding our request to the queue
    requestQueue.add(jsonReq);
}


protected void parseJsonFeed(JSONObject response, String pk_int_kv_category_id, String vchr_kv_category_name, String fk_int_kv_category_id, String vchr_delete_status, String vchr_last_modified_by, String vchr_last_modified_time) {
    try {

        JSONArray categoey_array = response.getJSONArray(JSON_ARRAY);
        for(int i=0;i<categoey_array.length();i++) {
            JSONObject feedobj=(JSONObject) categoey_array.get(i);

            pk_int_kv_category_id1 = feedobj.getString(pk_int_kv_category_id);
            vchr_kv_category_name1 = feedobj.getString(vchr_kv_category_name);
            fk_int_kv_category_id1 = feedobj.getString(fk_int_kv_category_id);
            vchr_delete_status1  = feedobj.getString(vchr_delete_status);
            vchr_last_modified_by1 = feedobj.getString(vchr_last_modified_by);
            vchr_last_modified_time1 = feedobj.getString(vchr_last_modified_time);
            Toast.makeText(this,vchr_kv_category_name.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    }catch (JSONException jsonexception){
        Toast.makeText(this,jsonexception.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
}
```

But While running my application i'm getting the following error

> value [{"pk_int_kv_category_id":1,"vchr_kv_category_name":"Parent","fk_int_kv_category_id":1,"vchr_delete_status":"s","vchr_last_modified_by":1,"vchr_last_modified_time":1},{"pk_int_kv_category_id":2,"vchr_kv_category_name":"Events","fk_int_kv_category_id":1,"vchr_delete_status":"s","vchr_last_modified_by":123,"vchr_last_modified_time":"2017-08-23 14:46:04"}] of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject

Comment: Call `JsonArrayRequest` instead of `JsonObjectRequest`.

Comment: Thanks.. :-)  @Krupa Kakkad

Comment: Happy Coding..!

Answer (score 1):

change this lines

```
JSONArray categoey_array = response.getJSONArray(JSON_ARRAY);

JSONObject feedobj=(JSONObject) categoey_array.get(i);
```

to

```
JSONArray categoey_array = new JSONArray(json string);//put here your json string

JSONObject feedobj = categoey_array.getJSONObject(i);
```